# Logging Request and Response values for a WCF request in client

Tags: wcf, logging, request, client, response

I am trying to log the request ad response messages in my client while the client is consuming a thirdparty WebService.

Despite of many attempts the log file - MessageLog.svclog never gets created using the following WCF configuration in the app.config file. Please help.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source
     name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
     switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="yourTrace"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="C:\Log\MessageLog.svclog">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
<messageLogging
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
        logMalformedMessages="true"
        logEntireMessage="true"
        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000" maxMessagesToLog="500" />
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Notice the SharedListeners node

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" 
          switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="C:\Log\MessageLog.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    ...
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I replaced the existing with your block of config statements and executed my application. But still, nothing is been logged. Anything else to be tried out to get it loggging?

Comment: Is this in the app.config on your service or client? Are there any permission issues? Maybe you can try to save it to a different location?

Comment: This is in client. Tried to save to different location too. But does not log.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I have my client which is consuming a third party service and I want to see the message log to debug the data sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with WS Client tracing where App.config and folder permissions were totally ok. The solution in my case was that I renamed it to .exe.config (was built to .dll.config of the WS client dll). So make sure:

1. That the name in the folder of the config file matches the assembly name
2. That when you run/debug it, the assembly that config file is for, is really used and not assembly for other location.
3. If it is built into .dll.config it is maybe ignored cause it should be .exe.config.

-m